# Returning exit 0/1 from powershell/Bash Script

Tags: c#, bash, powershell

I am calling an exe(c# code) from my powershell script (Can use bash too) and it works fine.

Now, I want to return something like true/false from my exe and if it is true then my other bash script will return exit 0 else exit 1.

My current ps script is something like this :

```
& C:\Users\location\Test.exe Parameter1
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: _"return something like"_ is that as an exit code or output on std:io? Because if we are speaking of exit codes, commonly a 0 is read as "no errors". See also for example: [Environment.Exit - Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.exit?view=net-6.0#remarks)

Comment: I can return anything from my c# code like an exit code or true/false. Something that says it passed or failed. Would be great if I can return couple or more exit codes though.

Comment: You exit only once, so that doesn't make sense, really. You _can_ do process I/O. But there is only one exit with exit code.

Comment: I was thinking that in my bash file, I can have certain if conditions with what exit code came from my c# files. Also not sure if c# has static void main, how can I return something. Sorry, new to this.

Comment: You can make it `static int Main`. In case of void the default exit code will be 0, afaik. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/main-command-line#main-return-values

Comment: ^^ There is even a PowerShell example of how to use it.

Comment: I see do a `static int Main` and return whatever number I want and in my bash script have if condition that if the number matches then do this else this. Got it. That should be ok right ?

Comment: And have the script like Farid ? It would wait for the exit code before it runs the if condition there ?

Comment: The `-Wait` makes it wait, yes. Mind that it is commonly accepted that 0 means "successful execution" or "no errors" while non-0 Exit _usually_ indicates some sort of error.

Comment: @Fildor I tried below code from Farid but ExitCode comes empty even when I mention 0 explicitly and it doesn't work with parameters.

Comment: Can you make the simplest possible exe (just returning 0) to test your script? Then after that the next more complex: returning the first arg ?

Comment: Thats what I tried just returning 0 without any parameter with static int Main.

Comment: When I do without arg, and when I do process.ExitCode in ps, it returns empty.

Comment: Hmmm, I'll have to try that. But I am on a windows machine only on monday, so maybe someone with a windows machine can take this?

Comment: Yeah, would be helpful if someone helps out

Answer (score 0):

you can start your exe in a process and get the return code.
(with $EXECUTABLE and $arglist containing the executable paht and the arguments to pass respectively)

```
$process = Start-Process $EXECUTABLE -argumentlist $arglist -Wait

# check the exit code of the process
if (0 -eq $process.ExitCode) {
    exit 0
}
exit 1
```

Comment: so this will be a bash file right ? like .sh ? And what should be the return type from exe (c# files) like true/false or some code ?

Comment: I tried something like this and it doesnt work. Gives me argList error. `$process = Start-Process  C:\Users\location\Test.exe $ParamValue -Wait`.

Comment: If I run without the Param and change the code to not have any param input with something like `$process = Start-Process  C:\Users\location\Test.exe -Wait` , then the $process.ExitCode comes empty.

Comment: @user19011893 your code should return 0 in success 1 if false (the executable) this is a powershell (.ps1) not bash

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your C# application is a *console* application:

- Make it `return` an `int` from its `Main` method, which becomes the *process exit code* when your application is called; by convention, an exit code of `0` signals success, whereas any non-zero value indicates failure.

  - [Fildor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/982149/fildor) provided the [relevant documentation link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/main-command-line#main-return-values) for the appropriate static `Main` method signatures in a comment.

On the scripting side:

- Bash:

  - If the call to your C# executable is the *last* command in your script, its exit code will *implicitly* be passed through, i.e. it will become the script's exit code; otherwise, save the exit code, as reported in the built-in `$?` variable, in a variable and pass that to `exit` later.
- PowerShell:

  - PowerShell reports the exit code of the most recently executed *external program* in its [automatic `$LastExitCode` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode).
  - Unlike in Bash, exit codes are never *automatically* passed through, so you'll need to do the following to make your PowerShell script report your C# application's exit code:

    ```
    & C:\Users\location\Test.exe Parameter1
    exit $LASTEXITCODE
    ```

---

Note that there's rarely a good reason to use [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) to invoke *console* applications in PowerShell. *Direct* invocation, as shown in your question, ensures:

- *synchronous* (blocking) execution
- that the application's output streams (stdout, stderr) are connected to PowerShell's streams, allowing them to be captured
- reporting of the process exit code in `$LASTEXITCODE`

Answer (score 0):

I think here's what you can do what you wanted to do:

A pseudocode example of your c# program:

```cs
class Program
{
    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
           int var;
           //do whatever you want to do here
        and store a number in var, depending on what you did

       return var;
    }
}
```

then from your bash script, run the program and store the returned value in a variable:

```bash
...
return_value=$(/path/to/your/exe argument)

#If block to perform different tasks depending on the returned value

if [ $return_value -eq 1 ]; then
  
     #do what it supposed to do when returned value is 1.

elif [ $returned_value -eq 2 ]; then
     
     #do what it supposed when returned value is 2.

elif [ $returned_value -eq 3 ]; then

     #do what it supposed to when returned value is 3.

...

fi
```